# ASP .NET Core OpenID Connect - Issuing my own cookie after external login?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I am using the OpenID Connect nuget package (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect`) in my
.NET 5 Web API in order to log in users through Azure AD (personal or work accounts). This is all done via this setup in Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "AAD", o =>
    {
        o.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.UsePkce = true;

        o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0";
        o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // dev only

        o.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
        o.ClientId = "azure AD application ID";
        o.ClientSecret = "my secret";
        o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        o.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query;
        o.CallbackPath = "/auth/microsoft/callback";

        o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = true;
        o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
        o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = "azure AD application ID";
        o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new List<string>
        {
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/v2.0", // for personal account login
            // add other tenant ID's here
        };
    })
    .AddCookie(o =>
    {
        o.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
        {
            // Return an Access Denied code rather than the Cookie default of /Account/AccessDenied page
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

This works great, and my user gets authenticated via a Cookie and can access routes restricted with the `[Authorize]` attribute. The `HttpContext.User` contains claims about the Azure AD user - like the "Subject", their email, preferred username, and tenant Id.

However, my application has it's own User class, with it's own stuff I would want to add to claims. **I only want to use OpenID Connect for the login part** - to lookup the user in the "UserLogins" table which contains information about a Users' external login (Microsoft, Google, etc). In my mind this is what it would look like:

1. User authenticates with OpenID Connect provider.
2. I get the User "Subject", which is their unique ID for that provider.
3. I use the subject to lookup the record in the "UserLogins" database table, and match that to a record in the "Users" table.
4. I issue my own cookie with claims that are relevant to my application (such as the "UserId" from the Users table)

What is the best way to do this?
Do I continue using the Cookie issued by Azure AD? Or is it a good option to issue my own Cookie?
Do I have to set up a different Cookie authentication scheme for that?
I was thinking I could potentially use and IClaimsTransformation to add or override the claims relevant to my application to the same Cookie, but wasn't sure if this was a "proper" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The claims about the authenticated user are asserted by the OpenID Provider, and you can't modify them. If you want to pass to your frontend application any more claims, you would have to put it in a different token or cookie. If you only need the data in the backend, you can read from the database whenever you get a request.